# how to add whole latest accessible artifacts in a repository as dependency in maven pom file at once?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, artifactory

I have a local repository with more than 250 artifacts(jar files) in there and on the other hand I have a project that should use all of these jar files. How can I add all latest jars in repository as dependency in POM file of my project at once ? Is there a command ?

Comment: Simply no. You have to add those dependencies to your pom file...apart from that I doubt that you need to give all of them cause one of the is using others so called transitive dependencies...

Comment: unfortunately those are only external jars, I use Artifactory and I places all of them into a groupId called org.externals, I hope maybe Artifactory could create list of dependency declarations for me ?

Comment: Why do you need all of these dependencies? It is really unusual to have 250 dependencies and as khmarbaise already said, dependencies usually have a POM that references other dependencies, so you only need to add those which you directly use.

Comment: Its a big ERP system developed since past 10 years and I am the one who responsible to reorder and manage dependencies. there are a lot pf problems like circular dependencies and these projects use class path, I am going to change them to maven structure